# Is there a way to keep data when Kubernetes cluster is down

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cloud, storage, kubernetes-pvc

I currently have a kubernetes cluster in the cloud (EC2). My services are using persistant volume claim because we absolutely need to keep the data. If my PVC would be erased, I would loose all the data which is not acceptable.

My understanding is that my PVC are bound to my cluster and if I shut down my cluster, I would lose all my PVC and therefore all my data, which mean I would not be able to manage the cost of my EC2. Fro example, I would like to shut down the cluster for the week end or overnight as it's not used and would reduce my AWS cost.

Is there a way to keep data state so that if I have a state X on friday, when I restart my cluster on monday I'm able to start it with my storage with state X ?

Thanks!

Comment: If your "shutdown" doesn't involve deleting the PVC's while the cluster is up then the EBS auto provisioned volumes won't be removed. If you are still concerned, set the pv `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` to `retain` to enforce manual cleanup of pvc resources.